# How to test Input and mat option inside Mat select in Angular

Tags: css, angular, dom

I have the following below code in my Html file :

Product.html

```
<mat-select id="selectProduct"
            placeholder="Product"
            multiple
            [(ngModel)]="request.selectedProductIds"
            #productModel="ngModel"
            disableOptionCentering
            (openedChange)="openedChange($event,'productFilterText')"
            panelClass="contnetPanel"
            #demo>
    <input id="txtFilterProduct"
           [(ngModel)]="productFilterText"
           class="mat-select-filterbox"
           placeholder="Search Product"
           autocomplete="off"
           (keyup)="filterProducts($event.target.value)" />
    <div class="matOptionList">
        <mat-option #matOption
                    *ngFor="let pfoduct of masterData.product"
                    [value]="product.id"
                    (click)="onproductClick(matOption,product)">{{product.name}}</mat-option>
    </div>
</mat-select>
```

I want to write Unit test case in Angular for input element inside mat-select element in .ts file like below:

```
 it('open the product dropDown', async(() => {
            componentFixture.detectChanges();
            spyOn(searchComponent, 'filterProducts');
            let input = componentFixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#txtFilterProduct'));
            input.triggerEventHandler('keyup', null);
            componentFixture.detectChanges();
            expect(searchComponent.filterProducts).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(searchComponent.filterProducts).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        }));
```

I am getting the error: calling triggerEventHandler on undefined.
Similarly it is giving the same error for mat-option.

Please suggest or tell how we can do unit test for input and mat-option inside mat-select for dropdown

Comment: Can you check and confirm whether there are any `*ngIf` condition stopping it from rendering. The error seems to be because it can't find `txtFilterProduct` element using `By.class` . I hope the import for `By` is also correct

Comment: @ShashankVivek : there are no *ngIf conditions and import for by is also correct i.e. import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';